# what is oauth and How does Website Implement it

Tags: php, html, jsp, oauth

I know the question is Kinda  Silly but i want to know what exactly is oauth and how does it work with facebook,twitter etc.

And also if i want to implement it for my website like creating a login from my website button how can i do it

Comment: this article explains how to implement it in php http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-php-oauth-server/ this article explains what is it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Definition

According to Wikipedia:

> OAuth is an open standard to authorization.OAuth provides client applications a 'secure delegated access' to server resources on behalf of a resource owner. It specifies a process for resource owners to authorize third-party access to their server resources without sharing their credentials.

So OAuth is commonly used as a way for web surfers to log into third party web sites using their Google, Facebook or Twitter accounts.

## Working Example

Lets say you have a Gmail Account. You decide to sign up for LinkedIn.Adding your friends manually can be sketchy and painful. You might get fed up half-way. So you might be tempted not to create an the LinkedIn account after all.

LinkedIn got a nice idea and wrote a program to let the computer fetch all the data from your Gmail Account.

Without an API for exchanging this list of contacts, you may have to comprimise your email account to LinkedIn so here is where OAuth takes charge. If your Gmail supports the OAuth protocol, then LinkedIn can ask you to authorize them to access your GMail list of contacts.

***References :***

*1)*http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

*2)*https://blog.apigee.com/detail/when_to_use_oauth